# Maximo Anywhere First Time Download Failure

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am working on Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 - Work Execution Application. After deploying the app, On successful Login. I am getting "isFirstTimeWorkListDownloadFailure" for the querybase "getMyAssignedWork". Kindly help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There're a lot of reasons for this issue try to open the app in chrome console check the error messages there